# VBScript - check if mailItem is still viable

Tags: vbscript, mailitem

I've ran into a problem with one of my scripts.
The script automates our shared mailbox (outlook). It auto-assigns mails to the correct person.

Everytime the script runs, it loops all the mails in the folder and checks if it has a category. If not, it assigns it to the right user.
Problem is, when a mail with no category gets dragged to another folder while running the script, it throws an error when trying to execute mail.Categories

> Line: 222
>   Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 8004010f.

Is there a way to check if the mailItem is still viable?

I tried using IsEmpty, but the msgbox doesn't trigger.

```
Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set namespace = outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

Set Account = namespace.Folders("accountName")
Set Inbox = argentaAccount.Folders("Inbox")

For Each mail in Inbox.Items

    If IsEmpty(mail) Then
        MsgBox("test")
    End If

    'check if item has a category'
    If mail.Categories <> "" Then
        'has a category'
    Else
        'Execute mailhandling code'
    End If
Next
```

If anyone has any solution, I would be forever grateful.

Answer (score 0):

With this line as a clue:

```
If IsEmpty(mail) Then
```

VBScript may work the same as VBA where For Each works like:

```
For i = 1 to Inbox.Items.Count
```

When item 1 is moved (or deleted), item 2 moves into position 1. On the next loop, position 2 with item 3 is processed. Every second item is skipped. In the second half of the loop there is nothing to process.

One way of dealing with this in VBA is to step in reverse order:

```
For i = Inbox.Items.Count to 1 step -1
    Set mail = Inbox.Items(i)
    If mail.Categories <> ""
```